# How to send a Text message received from SMSC to the user

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, smpp, kannel

After reading the SMPP v3.4 doc I am able to understand following concepts:

1. ESME or SMS-Gateway(currently I am using kannel) will the send the message to SMSC
2. SMSC will send it to the receiver or SMSC or some other entities
3. Similarly when SMSC receive the message it will send it back to SMS Gateway or ESME

Currently in my project I have only one SMSC connection. So when I receive a message from SMSC to ESME application to deliver to a user say User A, should I send the message back to SMSC so that it will deliver it to the respective User

As per as my knowledge it is always the SMSC who delivers the message not the ESME. Is there any better approach or am I wrong somewhere??

Comment: To make myself clear, you're sending a sms using the SMSC to the Kannel?

Comment: @Kulasagar: Yup, I am using kannel. the sms-service group will provide the message to kannel

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must have an `SMPP SMSC/ANY GSM MODEM` to deliver and capture sms

```
SMPP SMSC / GSM MODEM <------> KANNEL GATEWAY
```

You can send and receive using this configuration if your operator support MO and MT sms